# char operations on byte arrays in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, character-arrays

I have a byte array which "contains" text - the encoding/charset is unkown at this time.

How can I remove whitespace, \n, \r  characters, of course without creating a String object from the byte array ?

The goal is to display the byte array as text, with a charset specified by the user, just without these whitespace, \n, \r  characters.

Comment: This isn't possible; without knowing the character set, you don't know, for example, whether an `0x0a` byte is a newline or part of a UTF code point.

Comment: without creating a String object??? of course you need to create an object to enable you to modify its value

Comment: @chrylis: 0x0a is never a part of a UTF code point.

Comment: @KarolS Nonsense. The UTF-16 encoding for the code point U+010A `Ċ` (Latin Capital Letter C with dot above) has an `0x0a` in it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was thinking UTF-8 only. You're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a byte array which "contains" text - the encoding/charset is unkown at this time.

If you don't know the encoding, then there is simply no *concept* of whitespace, `\r`, `\n` characters etc. Those characters could map to *any* bytes.

You *must* determine the encoding before you can reliably perform *any* text-based operations. Until then, you simply don't have text.

So basically you need to reorder your steps: ask the user for the encoding, *then* convert the byte array into text, *then* remove whitespace (e.g. with a regular expression).